# Regex to extract paths both in Unix and Windows

Tags: c#, regex

I've written an application in .NET which gets a path from the executing assembly. It returns to me something like this:

**In MacOS:**

`file:/RiderProjects/Aquamon/Aquamon/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0`

**In Windows**

`file:\C:\RiderProjects\Aquamon\Aquamon\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0`

The thing is, to process those strings and obtain just the path I need to detach the `file:` part, so I wrote two different regexes:

`(?<!file\/)\/+[\S\s]*` for MacOS,

and

`(?<!fil)[A-Za-z]:\\+[\S\s]*` for Windows.

The issue is I would like to summarize both expressions in only one... but I can't seem to do it. The reason why I ended up with two was because in Windows I needed to extract that extra `\` before the `C:\...`, which is not present in other systems.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel, use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try [`@"(?s)(?<=file:(\\)?)(?(1)[A-Za-z]|/).*"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dfile%3a%28%5c%5c%29%3f%29%28%3f%281%29%5bA-Za-z%5d%7c%2f%29.*&i=file%3a%2fRiderProjects%2fAquamon%2fAquamon%2fbin%2fDebug%2fnetcoreapp2.0%0d%0afile%3a%5cC%3a%5cRiderProjects%5cAquamon%5cAquamon%5cbin%5cDebug%5cnetcoreapp2.0).

Comment: Or, [`(?s)(?:/|(?<=\\)).*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%2f%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5c%29%29.*&i=file%3a%2fRiderProjects%2fAquamon%2fAquamon%2fbin%2fDebug%2fnetcoreapp2.0%0d%0afile%3a%5cC%3a%5cRiderProjects%5cAquamon%5cAquamon%5cbin%5cDebug%5cnetcoreapp2.0). BTW, why not replace with `file:\\?` pattern? `Regex.Replace(s, @"file:\\?", "")`?

Comment: @Steve I don't think that will handle a local file URI?

Comment: @Steve how do you suggest doing it with the `Path` class? I didn't find any method to handle my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be what you want:

```
var pattern = @"(?<=file:\\?)[^\\].+";
var ans = Regex.Match(aPath, pattern).Value;
```